# Get Multiple Input Values from same class and store it in a json variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I got here a multiple values that store its data on an array. I expected that the data from the field will be seperated from each line.

Actual Result:
["firstname","middlename","lastname","bday","firstname", ...]

Expected : ["firstname","middlename","lastname","bday"],["firstname","middlename","lastname","bday"]

Please see code below:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnAddChild").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#childinfo_div").append('<div class="col-xl-3"><div class="form-group child_sub"><p>First Name:</p><input type="text" class="form-control" id="child_fname" /></div></div>');
    $("#childinfo_div").append('<div class="col-xl-3"><div class="form-group child_sub"><p>Middle Name:</p><input type="text" class="form-control" id="child_mname" /></div></div>');
    $("#childinfo_div").append('<div class="col-xl-3"><div class="form-group child_sub"><p>Last Name:</p><input type="text" class="form-control" id="child_lname" /></div></div>');
    $("#childinfo_div").append('<div class="col-xl-3"><div class="form-group child_sub"><p>Birthdate:</p><input type="date" class="form-control" id="child_bday" /></div></div>');

  });
});

function GetInfo() {
  var info = [];
  $(".child_sub").each(function() {

    $(this).children("input").each(function() {
      info.push(this.value);
    });

  });
  console.log(info);
  event.preventDefault();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="btnAddChild">ADD</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" onclick="GetInfo();"> GET INFO</button>
<div class="row" id="childinfo_div">

</div>
```

Comment: You need and indexer so that you can create multuple arrays so then you [0] [1] and so on, i would change your append method and use and object builder to then index elements as required.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is because you're looping over the `input` elements in `.child_sub` directly. As such you're creating a single array containing all values.

To create the structure you want, which is a nested array you need to loop over each collection, then each input within that, something like this:

```js
$(function() {
  $("#btnAddChild").click(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    var $row = $('<div class="child_sub_container"></div>');
    $row.append('<div class="col-xl-3"><div class="form-group child_sub"><p>First Name:</p><input type="text" class="form-control" id="child_fname" /></div></div>');
    $row.append('<div class="col-xl-3"><div class="form-group child_sub"><p>Middle Name:</p><input type="text" class="form-control" id="child_mname" /></div></div>');
    $row.append('<div class="col-xl-3"><div class="form-group child_sub"><p>Last Name:</p><input type="text" class="form-control" id="child_lname" /></div></div>');
    $row.append('<div class="col-xl-3"><div class="form-group child_sub"><p>Birthdate:</p><input type="date" class="form-control" id="child_bday" /></div></div>');
    $row.appendTo('#childinfo_div');
  });

  $('#btnGetInfo').on('click', function() {
    var info = $('.child_sub_container').map(function() {
      return [$(this).find(".child_sub input").map(function() {
        return this.value.trim();
      }).get()];
    }).get();

    console.log(info);
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"></script>
<button class="btn btn-info btn-sm" id="btnAddChild">ADD</button>
<button class="btn btn-success" id="btnGetInfo">GET INFO</button>
<div id="childinfo_div"></div>
```

Note that I removed the inline `onclick` attribute they are outdated and should not be used. I changed the logic to use an unobtrusive event handler instead.

I would also suggest you look in to cloning the `input` elements you add to the DOM when 'Add' is clicked, or using a templating library, as having that much HTML within your JS logic is bad practice.

Comment: I try the code in my local but the log is giving me a logical error. I dynamically added 2 forms but the console.log results that there is 6 array that includes 3 arrays that is empty and 2 arrays that includes the data i entered

Comment: That sounds like the selectors are picking up more elements in the HTML than expected. Check how many `.row` elements there are in the DOM, and change that class name to something unique if required.

Comment: I see i have another .row in my html. How can i replace the .row? i change the .row for something unique but the design is ruined because im using bootstrap

Comment: I changed the `.row` class name to `.child_sub_container`. Hopefully that's now unique within your page.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, i re-constructed the .row and create a new one and used it in the dynamic div. Many thanks!